# Semantic UI Search - filter fields

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, semantic-ui

I recently set up a search field in my Rails website using a semantic UI searchbox.

I'm searching through a JavaScript array, where each element in the Array has a title and a description, as the same array is used in Ruby for a overview grid.

When I type in the textbox I get the title as well as the description previewed, but I only want the title to be previewed.

My JavaScript code looks like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  $('.ui.search')
    .search({
    source : content,
    searchFields   : [
      'title'
    ],
  });
}
```

I've looked trough the documentation and examples but I've not found something like "showFields" where I can make a selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself, I had to define the fields manually and leave the description field blank

```
  $('.ui.search')
  .search({
    source : content,
    fields : {
      title : 'title',
      description: ''
    },
    searchFields   : [
      'title'
    ],
  });
```